# Copy a template part "header" that I want to duplicate and change a bit for a different page

Tags: templates

Is there any way to "duplicate" a template part. I'm in FSE 2023 and I see a way to create new template parts however I don't see a way to duplicate them.

I need a way to duplicate a header for a different page.